# Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

List dataListWidget(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.docs[0].map((document) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(document["Name"]),
subtitle: Text(document["City"]),
);
}).toList();
}

//my streamBuilder

StreamBuilder(
stream: firestore.collection('customers').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
return ListView(
children: dataListWidget(snapshot),
);
},
),`

Comment: Please format the code using ``` and are you sure the data is present in the firestore ?

Answer (score 0):

The query which you just fired returns empty mean it doesn't have any response in it and without checking any condition you are trying to access its 0th element.

You should do something like this

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream:firestore.collection('customers').snapshots(),
  builder:(context,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
      return ListView(children: dataListWidget(snapshot),); 
    }
    return Container();
});
```

And your dataListWidget should Look like this

```
List dataListWidget(AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
  if(snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty){
    return snapshot.data.docs[0].map((document) { 
      return ListTile( 
        title: Text(document["Name"]), subtitle: Text(document["City"]), 
        );
    }).toList();
  }
  else{
    return [Container()];
  }
}
```